# Mac Omniauth: (google_oauth2) :Faraday::SSLError (SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server certificate B: certificate B

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, ssl, omniauth, google-oauth

I have tried all possible ways available  to solve it still not able to solve this .
I am able to call all other sites.

Comment: https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/wiki/Setting-up-SSL-certificates did you see it?

Comment: I have tried following the steps, still no help. getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  I don't have a great solution, but I have a direction I'm heading.  I've found that ruby throws this error while jruby installs the auth json in the .certficates folder.

Ruby failed for me with this exact error.  I installed jruby, installed the google api gem and ran the same code.  It worked.

I turned around, and ran that code in ruby and it worked too since they were looking at the same .credentials folder.  The json times out and it can be replicated again. jruby installs the auth cert, ruby seems to fail.